# Windows Defender keeps taking action on nonexistent threats on nonexistent scans

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, windows-defender

I have a laptop (Dell Inspiron 3541) running Windows 10 v1803. Recently, I have been getting notifications from Windows Defender saying threats were found and removed on scnas that didn't happen.

Some of the notifications are:

> Windows Defender successfully took action on 3 threats since your last summary. You device was scanned 1 time.

and

> Windows Defender successfully took action on 1 threat since your last summary. You device was scanned 2 times.

When I go to Windows Defender, it doesn't show any threats found - nor does it even show a recent scan. For example, I got one of the above notifications today, and this is what Windows Defender showed.

[image: Windows Defender]

I tried running a scan, but the ETA was 4 hours, then 20, then 70, and still kept going up.

Is there a way I can find out what the "threats" are? Or make it stop sending these unnecessary notifications?

Answer (score 1):

You may turn off some notification options in
the *Windows Defender Security Center*, section
*Virus & threat protection*. Click
*Virus & threat protection settings*,
scroll down and click
*Change notification settings*, then disable the ones you don't like.

I have solved my problem of dummy popups as described below,
without changing the notification settings.

Again in the *Windows Defender Security Center*, section
*Virus & threat protection*, click on *Threat history*.

Do not be misled by the message of "No threats".
Click on both links of *See full history*, which may show some items.
For each items click *See details* to check which file it is, and if
not a threat then click *Allow*.

After this Defender will calm down, although there will still be
one notification in the Action Center.
If it bothers you, turn it off as described above,
but it might still be useful.